# Register or remove middleware without deploying code

Tags: asp.net-core, middleware

I have created a middleware which logs requests/response data in the database.
I want this middleware to work only when I want to troubleshoot defect or unwanted exception. The middleware should not log rest of the time.
I want a switch button which I can on or off on any controller without making any code changes and deployment.

Please suggests the ways to achieve the above.

Answer (score 1):

In Program.cs, you can add conditionally a middleware like :

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
...
var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Configuration.Get<bool>("MiddlewareLog.Enable"))
{
    app.UseCustomeLoggerMiddleware();
}
...
```

To enable/disable the middleware, you only need to update the appsettings.json and restart the web api/app.

Comment: But changing the appsetting.json required deployment/approval in production environment.

Comment: It isn't a api? It's a web application with razor IHM?

Comment: It is a .net core api. I got your point of introducing the key in the app settings and restarting the api. Is it possible to do it without restarting the api service and having the switch not in appsettings.json file?

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to enable/disable the middleware from a global setting. Then the controller's action can modify this global setting to enable/disable the middleware.

```cs
public class LoggerMiddleware
{
    public static volatile bool Enable;

    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public LoggerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        if(Enable)
        {
            // Log
        }
        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

```
[Route("logger")]
public class LoggerController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public void EnableOrDisable(bool enable)
    {
        LoggerMiddleware.Enable = enable;
    }
}
```

In the example, I use a static field, but it's possible to inject a singleton service in the middleware and the controller to share the setting.